# What is the proper way to URL encode JavaScript in a bookmarklet?

Tags: javascript, url, encode

I've seen 3 different ways now.  All encoding different sets of characters.

Some encode `;` while others do not. ( [this tool](http://www.url-encode-decode.com/) does encode it )

Some encode `)` while others do not. ( [this tool](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/) does not encode it )

Code submitted to me was different than both above and I don't know what tool they used.

What is the correct way to URL encoded data.  Their does not seem be consistency on the internet and its various tools.

Here is a good list of special characters from wikipedia:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

Here is an exhaustive list from that domain people don't like to mention:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986

Comment: or just use browser console and `encodeURIComponent`

Comment: Tangentially related: I did some research regarding necessary encoding for textual **dataURIs** (utf-8) and ended up with resolution, that only **newlines** (or potentially other control characters), **hash (`#`)** and **percent (`%`)** characters needs to be escaped `whatever.replace(/[\0-\40\43\45]/g,encodeURIComponent)`; all other characters can remain unescaped and nothing will brake.